# arm_navigation stack: ompl node not recognising end effector/tip name for processing Cartesian Goals

Tags: ros, cartesian, arm-navigation, ompl-planning, parameter

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to utilise the OMPL node to generate trajectories.

I've been able to call the ompl_planning/getMotionPlan service on my ompl_planning node by ensuring I've sent through an empty planning_scene_diff_request which has allowed the environment server to share the planning scene.

However my ompl_node is now giving the error:

```
 Cartesian goals for link  are the only ones that can be processed
```

which a google search shows the error to be comming from [ompl_ros_joint_planner.cpp](http://mirror.umd.edu/roswiki/doc/diamondback/api/ompl_ros_interface/html/ompl__ros__joint__planner_8cpp_source.html), in particluar the lines:

```
    if (!(request.motion_plan_request.goal_constraints.position_constraints[i].link_name == end_effector_name_))
    {
       response.error_code.val = motion_planning_msgs::ArmNavigationErrorCodes::INVALID_LINK_NAME;
       ROS_ERROR("Cartesian goals for link %s are the only ones that can be processed", end_effector_name_.c_str());
       return false;      
     }
```

Now it seems that the error string is the end_effector_name_.c_str() as being equal to "", which is strange as it should be initialised by the parameter server as "Tool" as per this line of the same program:

```
node_handle_.getParam(physical_group_name+"/tip_name",end_effector_name_);
```

And this tip name is shown in the parameters here:

```
  /robot_description_planning/groups:
- {base_link: base_link, name: r_arm, tip_link: Tool}
- joints: [joint8, joint9]
  name: r_end_effector
```

So why can it not find the appropriate tip name from the parameter server and use it to recognise my planning goal request?

cheers

Peter

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/58372/arm_navigation-stack:-ompl-node-not-recognising-end-effector/tip-name-for-processing-cartesian-goals/) by [PeterMilani](https://answers.ros.org/users/3621/petermilani/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1493 on 2013-03-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was specifying the wrong planning group for cartesian goal poses. I was specifying "r_arm" group which as per above doesn't have a "tip name" parameter.

However, after looking through the other parameters in the server, it seems that the more appropriate planning group is the "r_arm_cartesian", which does have a parameter "tip_name"

This cleared the error, but opened up some more fundamental ones!

---

Originally posted by [PeterMilani](https://answers.ros.org/users/3621/petermilani/) with karma: 1493 on 2013-03-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0